# Change errors in password change serializer in rest-auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using Django rest-auth to have endpoints for my registration, password change, etc. I'm working with the password change endpoint which contains the old password, new password, and confirm password. I am trying to override somethings in the original serializer like adding my own error messages if the field is incorrect for example. However, one error message I'm having difficulty overriding is if the fields are blank. The default error message appears like so each time:

```
{
    "old_password": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "new_password1": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ],
    "new_password2": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

I'd like to implement my own error message if the field is blank, however, I am not able to do that. Here's the serializer I created:

```
class PasswordChange(PasswordChangeSerializer):

    set_password_form_class = SetPasswordForm

    def validate_old_password(self, value):
        invalid_password_conditions = (
            self.old_password_field_enabled,
            self.user,
            not self.user.check_password(value)
        )

        if all(invalid_password_conditions):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The password you entered is invalid.')
        return value
```

and here is the form class:

```
class PasswordForm(ChangePasswordForm):

    oldpassword = PasswordField(label=_("Current Password"))
    password1 = SetPasswordField(label=_("New Password"))
    password2 = PasswordField(label=_("Confirm New Password"))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['oldpassword'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": ""})
        self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": ""})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": ""})

    def clean_oldpassword(self):
        if not self.user.check_password(self.cleaned_data.get("oldpassword")):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password you entered is invalid."))
```

Am I doing this correctly? How can I change the error message that's displayed when the fields are blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`error_messages`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0eb2dc1137189027cc8d638630fb1754b02d6cfa/rest_framework/fields.py#L323) attribute of the `serializers.CharField`.

```
class PasswordChange(PasswordChangeSerializer):

    my_default_errors = 
            {
             'blank': 'your_message',
             'required': 'your_message',
            }
    old_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, error_messages=my_default_errors)
    new_password1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, error_messages=my_default_errors)
    new_password2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, error_messages=my_default_errors)

    def validate_old_password(self, value):
        invalid_password_conditions = (
            self.old_password_field_enabled,
            self.user,
            not self.user.check_password(value)
        )

        if all(invalid_password_conditions):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The password you entered is invalid.')
        return value
```

Comment: This works, however, I get this error: `'PasswordChangeSerializer' object has no attribute 'old_password_field_enabled'` I know I have to implement this, but after I implemented everything, I don't get correct error messages for when I need to confirm the password. For example, let's say I entered a new password that's not the same password when I confirm it. Instead of it saying the passwords don't match, it says This field can't be blank.

Comment: @user2896120 The `PasswordChange` class should inherit from `PasswordChangeSerializer`. I have corrected this in my answer. Could you please check again?

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, however, is it normal for the response to be a 400 bad request error if incorrect credentials are provided?

Comment: @user2896120 I think its Yes. From the documentation **These exceptions are automatically dealt with by the default exception handler that REST framework provides, and will return `HTTP 400 Bad Request` responses by default.**. See [this link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data) for more details

Comment: @user2896120 Also see the [`source code`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L143) too. DRF using `status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST` by default while raising `serializers.ValidationError`s.